# Would it be physically possible for rotating tank armor to move in front of an incoming projectile fast enough to intercept?

Tags: sensors

The core challenge of building a tank is deciding where to focus its armor and how much speed / cost you're willing to trade for protection, so this got me thinking, with modern detection technology, like laser, could we potentially place a single very thick plate of armor on an axle and once a projectile is detected, rotate it (around the outside of the tank) in front of the projectile in time to stop it (assuming it isn't a close quarter engagement).

If so, tanks could stay much lighter and much cheaper and still have all the benefits of extremely tough armor, and more importantly, have that same protection on all sides of the tank rather than just the front.

Question is: Is that physically possible? Is it physically possible with known modern technology to detect an incoming projectile, then rotate a wheel with enough torque and speed to intercept the projectile's path before it passes?

Factors I know:

- Fastest projectile should be traveling at 2000 m/s.
- Radius to be traveled around the sides of an average tank is 15 meters including the gun barrel.
- A 0.5 x 0.5 meter steel plate with a thickness of 120 mm will weigh 246 kg.
- Processing / detection time isn't relevant. The time between scanning the incoming projectile (twice, to calculate angle and speed) and sending the correct information to the armor acceleration mechanism is easily less than 1ms, during which the projectile has only traveled 2 meters since detection.

What I don't know:

- Assuming we use the best viable method known, how fast can that 246kg plate be accelerated to the correct location?
- Would it be better if the plate was kept in constant motion and simply adjusted once the projectile is detected so it doesn't need to be accelerated from a zero energy state.?

Other factors to consider:

- The armor doesn't *have* to be stopped right away. It can be accelerated to exactly the correct speed to be in front of the projectile at the calculated time and place of collision, then freely continue swinging around the tank and slow down gradually.
- There might need to be 2 equally sized plates on opposite ends of the tank to counter each other so the tank can remain stable - so potentially twice the weight.

Comment: First question how fast are the fastest missiles, then detection range, then how much time to detect, analyse and make decision, then how much time to transmit order, then how much time to move the shield and at what speed ? First two will give you a ball-park duration for all to be complete...

Comment: @SolarMike I added detail.

Comment: This is too broad to be meaningfully answered in StackExchange's Q&A format.  There are simply too many unknowns and assumptions that must be made.  For instance, what is supposed to occur when multiple projectiles are launched at the vehicle from different angles?

Comment: @GlenH7 "what is supposed to occur when multiple projectiles are launched at the vehicle from different angles?" that's irrelevant to the actual question itself, which is whether or not we can position the plate in time to intercept one projectile.

Comment: @johndoe defeating one prijectile to then be destroyed by another is not really very useful... you’re still burnt to a crisp...

Comment: @SolarMike fine but it's a question of engineering not battle strategy. I could argue that tanks wouldnt usually take multiple hits in under the short time it would take for the system to be ready to deflect the next incoming projectile - but this isnt really the place to discuss that. But if we were to discuss that then we could argue that the benefits outweigh the cost (weakness to 2 incoming projectiles from 2 different angles during the exact same second, an unlikely scenario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming we use the best viable method known, how fast can that 246kg
>   plate be accelerated?

It's not just a plate to accelerate, it's a [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) to fight and it depends on the position of the plate regarding the center of rotation, its geometry, thus depends on the design of the tank, then it depends on the acceleration curve of the motor and the initial position of the plate, etc.…

I think there is no engineer answer to your question, too many guesses and unsupported assumptions need to be made on too many variables without access to (classified) accurate data.

Like :

- "**How far a laser can detect an incoming projectile accurately**" : "accurately" needs to be defined, what is your maximum acceptable error of position ? Then, is it by clear weather or in the dust/storm/etc. ?
- "**What's the fastest scan rate that can be achieved by the laser detection system? We need to read 2 locations to determine the projectile's attack vector.**" : you certainly need to use satellites here, since the tank might be blinded by mountains etc. Thus, you need to take into account the latency of the transmission, the risk of data loss, etc. And you need at least 3 readings to achieve proper accuracy in a short amount of time. After that, you need to achieve a third-order accuracy reading on the missile acceleration in order to get a first-order accuracy on the position of the impact (since it's  a double integral). As you see, it's not just sensing and measuring, it's [differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations) to solve in real-time, thus the numeric overhead is significant.
- "**The armor doesn't have to be stopped right away. It can be accelerated to exactly the correct speed to be in front of the projectile at the calculated time and place of collision, then freely continue swinging around the tank and slow down gradually.**" : actually, using a moving armor is quite clever and might make good use of the conservation of the [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum). However, the very aspect of the automation control is a challenge here. Assuming you have the perfect motor (actuator) to do so, ensuring a proper control to achieve precision on position, speed and acceleration based on an acceleration and position input needs at least a 3rd-order accurate controler with a very fast numeric solver. Since your oversized motor won't probably have a linear response, you will have to correct that as well. So it's a lot of math to process with a lot of measures to gather and a lot of errors to handle in a short amount of time, and by the time you get the parameters to input in your motor controler, you might just be dead already.

Yes, physically, this is just basic newtonian mechanics and tennis playing with missiles, and it is possible in theory.

However, there is no definitive answer to the feasibility aspect until someone does it, and this is more sci-fi than engineering.

Comment: "you certainly need to use satellites here, since the tank might be blinded by mountains etc." I'm referring to tank vs tank engagements which can probably be limited to 0.5 - 1.5 kilometers and line of sight would be all that matters in those engagements. If the other tank can fire at mine, I have line of sight on that incoming projectile. 

If you look at my question again I just made some clarifications to remove some of the guesses, and I think consolidated my question.

Comment: Another thought: "Assuming you have the perfect motor (actuator) to do so, ensuring a proper control to achieve precision on position, speed and acceleration" could dynamically fueled raw combustion be used? Basically a calculation saying "we need to move exactly this far, at exactly this moment, so we need to insert exactly this much propellant", then create the motion in one swift action to simply some of the complexity you're outlining? Just a weird thought.

Comment: Also what did you think of the alternative of keeping the armor in motion, perhaps with a second identical armor plate on the other end as a counter weight? (constantly moving part might not be ideal, but less intense velocity change is required, and I guess you also get the accidental benefit of making it difficult for any enemy soldiers to approach the vehicle directly)

Comment: from what I know, a laser can either measure a speed or a static position, not both at the same time. So you need triangulation from 3 spots. To know the position of impact, you need the position, the speed and the acceleration of the projectile, and you will never get these data from a single point. What a laser measures is a radius in spheric coordinates, you are lacking 2 other coordinates.

Comment: "Basically a calculation saying "we need to move exactly this far, at exactly this moment, so we need to insert exactly this much propellant"," no, motion control is way more complicated than that since you are dealing with non-linearities everywhere and position errors. You need sensors to get feedback on your position, then processors to compute the error and adjust the input, and that's why robots took so long to emerge… We know the theory to control them since the 1970's but we just got the CPU to actually performs the computations

Comment: The laser can measure the position of the projectile twice, and the laser system can be designed to communicate these positions in relation to it's own position, that's 3.

Comment: it measures the position on 1 axis only, so even if you do it twice, you've got the magnitude of the speed vector but not its direction and certainly not its position in space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70672/discussion-between-john-doe-and-aurelien-pierre).